# Scrolling not possible on header area with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I've made working CollapsingToolbarLayout with this xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_header_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/header_top_shadow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_picture_top_shadow"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/header_bottom_shadow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_picture_bottom_shadow"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/save_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_save_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/uploading_photos_recycler"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="123dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

The only issue is, when I try to scroll on the header area it doesn't work. See the gif for example.

http://recordit.co/8hem1UkTHz

Looks like some library bug, but maybe I'm missing something?

EDIT:
As far I know it's a bug in design library

Comment: Image is not available. Check link

Comment: thanks, should be oknow

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in 23.0.1.